# Python: How to inherit and display the id defined in the class, rather than have to define it in the object

Tags: python, class, instantiation

I have the following Python code from a question on [www.testandtrack.io](http://www.testandtrack.io):

```
class Sales:
  def __init__(self,id):
    self.id=id
    id=321

val=Sales(123)
print(val.id)
```

The output here is:
123

I want to be able to display the value of the id of the object, but for it to be what is originally defined in the class, e.g. in this case '321'. I'd like to also understand how to override (as shown) when required, but leave class default attributes in when required.

I have tried leaving it blank on instantiation, but a positional argument is required.

```
val=Sales()
```

I've also tried to remove id from the 'constructor' function like below but that doesn't work either:

```
def __init__(self):
```

Could someone point me in the right direction with an explanation? I would like every object, by default, to inherit the id (or any specified attribute) of the class rather than have to explicitly define the values on creation. When required, for certain attributes, I would want to provide new values for the object, despite the value being defined in the class. (overriding)

Comment: `id=321` is simply setting a local variable.  It *ceases to exist* the moment the containing function returns.  Maybe that was supposed to be indented one level less, so that it's part of the class body?

Comment: Wait - but I now have the opposite question. If the below answer produces 321, how do I override it with 123?!

Comment: `def __init__(self,id=321):` would provide a default value for cases where the caller didn't provide a value for that parameter.

Comment: Your last paragraph sounds exactly what jasonharper is suggesting. If you `def f(a=1): return a`, you can either it call it like `f()` in which case a gets the default value of 1, or as f(2), in which can you provide it your own value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `321` is the default value in case no id is passed, you should do like this

```
class Sales:
   def __init__(self, id=321):
      self.id=id

val = Sales(123)
print(val.id) 
val2 = Sales()
print(val2.id)
```

Comment: but why am I still required to put in a positional argument for val=Sales(x) ...with x being the argument. Shouldn't I be able to leave that blank>?

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: https://replit.com/@benjr/MintySickSystemintegrator#main.py

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Sales:
  def __init__(self,id):
    self.id=id
    self.id=321

val=Sales(123)
print(val.id)
```

And the output will be 321

To edit the id of Sales, you have to put self. before.
Python is strict about it

Comment: Wait - but I now have the opposite question. If the below answer produces 321, how do I override it with 123?! If your answer could provide an explanation for how this works in terms of creating an object with the class value and then overriding it and having the option to do either ...

Comment: This is wrong. `self.id = id` is overwritten by the following line no matter what input you give it.

Comment: @Thomas what's point of the first assignment `self.id=id` anyway

Comment: @Reti43 - but even if you remove self.id=id it still does not overwrite it with the new value 123. class Sales:
  def __init__(self,id):
    #self.id=id
    self.id=321

val=Sales(123)
print(val.id)

Comment: @Compoot I am not following what you want to do. Do you want to keep both values 123 and 321 and be able to access in some way?

Comment: @nikeros I'd like to understand how to create an object with a specific value (in this case 123) but also how to, when required, inherit that value as default from the class. I understand how to override (with the method shown in the question) but someone has suggested self.id=id is pointless and perhaps not the way to do it. Also, I see how to inherit from the class, but then what's the point of the 123 being defined on instantiation?

Comment: @Compoot I'm talking specifically about this code snippet. If you do `a = 5` and in the very next line you do `a = 10`, the previous line is a *bit* pointless, innit?

Comment: To put it simply: if I defined this in the class: self.id=321 ....why do I still need to specify an argument on creation of the object. e.g. 123....val=Sales(123). Why can't I just leave it blank or what should I be doing? val=Sales() (if it is acquiring the 321 from the class attribute anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I didn't understand the question sorry.

Here is a way to do what you want to do :

```py
class Sales:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def set_id(self,id):
      self.id=id

val=Sales()
val.set_id(100)
print(val.id)
```

The answer will be 100

```py
class Sales:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def set_id(self,id):
      self.id=id

val=Sales()
val.set_id(100)
val.set_id(200)
print(val.id)
```

And for this one it will be 200

Comment: Is your way or Nikeros's more pythonic?